# Stargate SG-1 episode with religious conflict

Tags: stargate, episode-identification, stargate-sg1

I am looking for two things: a *Stargate SG-1* episode, which is between seasons 1 and 5, and a specific quote in that episode.

**Episode**

The SG-1 team visits a planet where they are met by a team of archaeologists, who have just found the Stargate of their planet. The arrival of SG-1 is a shock for the scientists, because they belong to a country where the main belief is that they originated on the planet. Their country is at war with the other continent, where people believe they used to be slaves and were brought through the Stargate a long time ago. I don't remember more, the team was partially captured I think?

**Quote**

The quote I am looking for is when a member of the team asks a scientist if he is sad that his belief was broken, and the scientist answers more or less "No, because that is what science is about". This answer is the quote I am looking for.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This might be "New Ground" (S3E19).

From [*Stargate SG-1* solutions](http://www.stargate-sg1-solutions.com/wiki/3.19_%22New_Ground%22_Episode_Guide):

> The SG-1 team travels to the planet Bedrosia where, unbeknownst to them, the planet's two cultures have been at war over their opposed beliefs regarding the Stargate. Upon their arrival, they are met by the curious Nyan, a scientist. Nyan explains to them that their arrival through the Stargate proves that the beliefs of his rival culture, the Optricans, is true and that humans were brought to this planet by aliens through a gateway. His culture, the Bedrosians, believe that human life evolved without a gateway and was created by their god, Nefertum.
>
> The team's arrival is soon detected by a group of Bedrosian soldiers and their leader, Rigar. Colonel Jack O'Neill, Major Samantha Carter, and Dr. Daniel Jackson are captured, while Teal'c and Nyan narrowly escape. During his escape, Teal'c is blinded. Rigar cages his three prisoners and interrogates them as to how they arrived on his planet. He believes that they are Optrican spies, when they insist they traveled via the Stargate. Rather than face the possibility that the entire belief system of his people is wrong, Rigar chooses to destroy all evidence, including SG-1. Though blinded, Teal'c with Nyan's help must outwit the Bedrosians before Rigar can execute his plan.

Especially, the [transcript](http://www.stargate-sg1-solutions.com/wiki/3.19_%22New_Ground%22_Transcript) has these lines:

> **Teal'c:** Nefertum was an under System Lord to the one named Ra. It is with him whom I did battle.
>
> **Nyan:** I don't understand. Nefertum was and is the creator of all of us. He created this planet and this great continent.
>
> **Teal'c:** Correction. Nefertum was an alien who most likely brought your people though the Stargate as slaves many thousands of years ago.
>
> **Nyan:** That is what the Optricans say.
>
> **Teal'c:** They are correct.
>
> **Nyan:** Oh dear Nefertum, this is blasphemy. If it is true, it could change everything. I must show my colleagues at the research academy.
>
> **Teal'c:** Can you be certain they will believe you?
>
> **Nyan:** They are scientists as I am. They will realise they are wrong when presented with the evidence.
>
> <sub>*Stargate SG-1*, Season 3 Episode 19, "New Ground"</sub>

The quote the OP was looking for is:

> **Teal'c:** Then perhaps you would be better off if I were no longer alive.
>
> **Nyan:** Teal'c, I'm a scientist. When I find evidence that my theories are wrong, it is as exciting as if they were correct. Scientific advance in either direction is still an advance.
>
> <sub>*Stargate SG-1*, Season 3 Episode 19, "New Ground"</sub>

---

Found with the Google query `stargate sg1 what science belief slaves war transcript`

Comment: The episode is the right one (Teal'c being blinded rings a bell) but that's not the quote I am looking for. I'll go look in the transcript.

Comment: FWIW I can't remember other related wording in the episode.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit In the first draft of this answer, I had included the first quote; OP then included the second one, which is the one they were actually looking for. Posting that in the comments for anyone who might not be aware of this post's revision history :)

Comment: @Jenayah Oh cool, thanks that makes more sense! Usually I check revision history and compare timestamps but today I couldn't be arsed :D

Comment: Love your final sentence btw

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit you're welcome! As for last line - my opinion only but I prefer it when people include how they found stuff. It certainly has helped me stepping up my Googling, so it's only natural I return the favor :)

Comment: Ironically, Teal'c is way more accepting of the claim in episode 1x02 that humans evolved on Earth, and he has nothing but the words of O'Neill and another air force officer. Then again, they did have the best chance he'd seen against the Goa'uld, so he was probably willing to believe it.

Comment: @Thunderforge O'Neill didn't turn up claiming to be the creation of a known Goa'uld. Teal'c also knows the legends of the Tau'ri and had no doubt heard the description of people that look like SG-1 being the ones that destroyed Ra